# Trying to train a spacy model using GPU but PyTorch throws the "Out Of Memory Error"

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, runtime-error, spacy-3

I'm Trying to build a parser to recognize entities from text given and to train the spacy model with GPU I went ahead and installed all the necessary packages but while training it runs the first iteration and throws the "Cuda Out Of Memory Error"

i was using this command on my terminal to train the model: python -m spacy train C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pythonProject3\config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./train_data.spacy --paths.dev ./test_data.spacy --gpu-id 0

And after the First Iteration it gives me this error:
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 12.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 4.99 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 5.33 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

What i dont seem to understand here is it mentions 0 bytes free. is there anything i can possibly do to provide some space and train my Model?